# Using timer with ProgressDialog

Tags: android, timer, progressdialog, countdowntimer, postdelayed

I have a method which is list my items from a server. Therefore, this method takes time until getting all the items. So I want to use ProgressDialog for waiting this method. I read some modules but I couldnt find any useful solution.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // setContentView(R.layout.main;
                    loginScreen();
        }
    public boolean getItems() throws MessagingException 
           {
                    items receiving here
           }
    public void loginScreen() 
           {
                   setContentView(R.layout.main);
                   Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

                   loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() 
                     {          
                      public void onClick(View arg0) 
                       {
                          getItems();
                       }
                     }
           }
```

On button Click I call the method which received all items. When I click the button I want to show a progressbar until all items getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an `AsyncTask` which shows an `ProgressBar` on `getItems()`. You need an `AsyncTask` because the main Thread will be busy fetching stuff from server and `ProgressBar` won't show up untill that is finished.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works almost like I want. Progressdialog is show when the method is preparing for the result but it is just too fast. So, the progressdialog shown so for short time. Can I add something (like timer) for delay the show of progressdialog for 2 second more?

Comment: all you gotta do is `Thread.sleep(2000);`, that will cause it to delay 2sec or 2000 milsec.